# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_atomic"

Tags: c++, boost, emscripten

I am compiling C/C++ to `wasm` with emscripten. And need `boost` library as well. Pretty new to `emscripten` and `wasm`

After installing emscripten and boost. I ran the following command

```
emconfigure cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=1
-Dboost_headers_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.71.0
-DBoost_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0 -Dboost_program_options_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.71.0
-Dboost_system_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.71.0 -Dboost_thread_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.71.0 -Dboost_unit_test_framework_DIR=../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_unit_test_framework-1.71.0
-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=${HOME}/.emscripten_ports/zlib/zlib-version_1 -DZLIB_LIBRARY=${HOME}/.emscripten_cache/asmjs -DBUILD_TESTING=0 -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBoost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON -DBUILD_EXEC=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF ..
```

I get the following error

```
CMake Error at /home/../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.71.0/boost_thread-config.cmake:91 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_atomic"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_atomicConfig.cmake
    boost_atomic-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_atomic" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_atomic_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_atomic" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

The `boost_atomic-config.cmake` is at `/home/../boost_1_71_0/build/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.71.0/boost_atomic-config.cmake`. How should I set the `boost_atomic_DIR` path to this file, as required above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a flag `-Dboost_atomic_DIR=/path/to/.cmake/file` in the above command and it worked.